# show icon in header only when on first tab - react native

Tags: react-native

I need to show an icon in header of a screen. The screen (My Offers) consists of two tabs (Offers and Offer Lists), but I want to show an icon when user is on the first tab but when user taps on the second tab, the icon in header musn't be shown:

```
function MyOffersTabNavigation() {
      const {theme} = useTheme();
      return (
        <TopTab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{
            labelStyle: {
              fontFamily: boldFont,
              fontSize: 15,
              textTransform: 'none',
              paddingVertical: 6,
            },
            activeTintColor: theme.topTab.topTabActiveColor,
            inactiveTintColor: theme.topTab.topTabInactiveColor,
            indicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: theme.topTab.topTabIndicatorColor,
              height: 2,
              bottom: -1,
            },
            style: {
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              borderBottomColor: theme.borderColor,
              backgroundColor: theme.topTab.topTabBgColor,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
              borderTopRightRadius: 30,
            },
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: theme.header.backgroundColor,
            paddingTop: 10,
          }}
          screenOptions={({navigation, route}) => {
            if (route.name === 'Offers' && navigation.isFocused()) {
              console.log("Offers") 
            } else if (route.name !== 'Offers' && navigation.isFocused()) {
              console.log("Offer Lists")
              
            }
          }}
          barStyle={{backgroundColor: mainBackgroundColor, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <TopTab.Screen name="Offers" component={MyOffersView}  />
          <TopTab.Screen name="Offer Lists" component={MyOffersListView} />
        </TopTab.Navigator>
      );
    }
```

Here I am using screenOptions to see what tab i'm on, I need Offers tab (name="Offers"), so when that tab is active, show icon in header.

I created this function so I can show Icon in header of My Offers screen:

```
function myOffersHeaderIco(route) {
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
  if (routeName === 'My Offers')  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then, I have this code where I simply show the icon based on the screen, so if the screen is My Offers, show icon:

```
export const getHeaderRight = (navigation, route) => {

  const {theme} = useTheme();
...
{/* My Offers screen */}
      {myOffersHeaderIco(route) ? 
      <View style={{marginRight:20}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this[RBSheet].open()}>
          <SortIcon color="#FFFFFF" />
          <RBSheet
            ref={(ref) => {
              this[RBSheet] = ref;
            }}
            closeOnDragDown={true}
            dragFromTopOnly={true}
            closeOnPressBack={true}
            closeOnPressMask={true}
            height={heightCalc}
            openDuration={260}
            customStyles={{
            container: {
              justifyContent: 'center',
              opacity: 1,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              paddingBottom: 20,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
              borderTopRightRadius: 30,
              backgroundColor: theme.bodyColor,
            },
            wrapper: {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'},
            draggableIcon: {
              backgroundColor: theme.borderColor,
              width: 38,
              marginVertical: 14,
              height: 4,
            },
          }}>
            <View style={bottomSheets.sheetContainer}>
              <View
                style={[
                  bottomSheets.sheetHeader,
                  {borderBottomColor: theme.borderColor},
                ]}>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    bottomSheets.sheetHeaderTitle,
                    {color: theme.sortTitles, fontSize:16,fontFamily:'NunitoSans-SemiBold'},
                  ]}>
                  Filter
                </Text>
              </View>
              <ScrollView style={bottomSheets.inputWrapper}>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    bottomSheets.inputLabel,
                    {color: theme.sortTitles, fontSize:15},
                  ]}>
                  Sort by Order
                </Text>
                  <PerformCheckBox
                  containerStyle={{
                    flex:1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent:'flex-start',
                    marginHorizontal:-10,
                  }}
                  key={1}
                  value={1}
                  bottomBorder
                  label={'  Ascending'}
                  clicked={(id, isCheck) => toggleCheckBox(id, isCheck)}
                />
                <PerformCheckBox
                  containerStyle={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    marginHorizontal:-10, 
                  }}
                  key={2}
                  value={2}
                  label={'  Descending'}
                  clicked={(id, isCheck) => toggleCheckBox(id, isCheck)}
                />
                <Text
                  style={[
                    bottomSheets.inputLabel,
                    {color: theme.sortTitles, fontSize:15,marginVertical: 20},
                  ]}>
                  Sort by
                </Text>
                  <PerformCheckBox
                  containerStyle={{
                    flex:1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent:'flex-start',
                    marginHorizontal:-10, 
                  }}
                  key={3}
                  value={3}
                  bottomBorder
                  label={'  Offer ID'}
                  clicked={(id, isCheck) => toggleCheckBox(id, isCheck)}
                />
                <PerformCheckBox
                  containerStyle={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    marginHorizontal:-10, 
                  }}
                  key={4}
                  value={4}
                  label={'  Offer Name'}
                  clicked={(id, isCheck) => toggleCheckBox(id, isCheck)}
                />
                <PerformCheckBox
                  containerStyle={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    marginHorizontal:-10,
                  }}
                  key={5}
                  value={5}
                  label={'  Status'}
                  clicked={(id, isCheck) => toggleCheckBox(id, isCheck)}
                />
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
            <View
              style={
                (bottomSheets.sheetFooter,
                {borderTopColor: theme.tabNav.borderTopColor, borderTopWidth: 1})
              }>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this[RBSheet].close()}
                style={bottomSheets.sheetFooterCenteredButton}>
                <Text style={bottomSheets.sheetFooterCenteredButtonLabel}>Done</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </RBSheet>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View> : null}
```

Then I am calling getHeaderRight like this:

```
const StackNavigation = (props) => {
  const {theme} = useTheme();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({navigation, route}) => ({
        gestureEnabled: true,
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
        ...TransitionPresets.ScaleFromCenterAndroid,
        cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        headerShown: props.headerShown,
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: theme.header.backgroundColor,
          shadowRadius: 0,
          elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
          shadowOffset: {
            // remove shadow for ios
            height: 0,
          },
        },
        cardStyle: {
          backgroundColor: theme.mainBackgroundColor,
          opacity: 1,
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleAlign: 'left',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontFamily: 'NunitoSans-Bold',
          marginLeft: props.headerTitleStyleMarginLeft,
          fontSize: 20,
          ...Platform.select({
            ios: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          }),

          color: 'white',
        },
        headerRight: () => getHeaderRight(navigation, route, props.user),

      })}>
```

Everything is working great except I cannot figure out how to get icon to show in header but only when the first tab is active, is there any way I could modify function myOffersHeaderIco(route) so I could pass route of that specific tab?

[image: these are my tabs and first icon is sorticon icon in header]

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the issue. You want to display the icon when Tab1 is active. In `myOffersHeaderIco(route)`, add

```
let isActive = false;

function myOffersHeaderIco(route) {
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
  if (routeName === 'My Offers')  {
    isActive = true;
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the view, add
`{isActive && <SortIcon color="#FFFFFF" />}`
If Tab1 is not active, hide the icon.

Comment: but i'm still not targeting the first tab, 
in this function: function myOffersHeaderIco(route) {
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
  if (routeName === 'My Offers')  {
    isActive = true;
    return true;
  }
} 
i am only checking if (routeName === 'My Offers') , My Offers is the whole screen, but i need to check the tab inside it, which is Offers, I dont know how to get tab1 
@Mike S.

Comment: icon is still showing in header of My Offers screen, no matter what tab is active  @Mike S.